How to get the brush pack for Grease Pencil Tools on Blender 4.3?
Using this YouTube tutorial in Blender 4.2 I am able to use this cool grass brush from the extension Grease Pencil Tools. But in Blender 4.3 I cannot find the option Download and import texture brush pack under Active Tool and Workspace settings.

How do I do I get these brushes for Blender 4.3? In Blender 4.2 it is this red-boxed option which is not available in 4.3.

@JohnEason Thank you. I took a look at this YT video, and yes, you can append the brushes and then mark them as assets, but when you use them, they are only black—the colors are gone. This method is just a workaround, though. There should be a way to install the brushes properly through the addon.

Fair enough. There's a section about the 4.3 Sculpt, Paint and Texture brushes on the Developer web site here. I've not read it but there might be something there to help.

It appears to me that what you want is a detailed answer instead of a brief one.  So, let's make a thorough answer for completeness.
As of Blender 4.3, the entire brush system was replaced by the Asset Library to streamline the customization process. That means all brushes and custom brushes can be converted into assets and automatically be used in any blender file. The creator of the Add-on that was included in your question has also noticed this and has thus notified us of discontinuing the import function. So, there is no way to import new brushes through his add-on.

What John Eason has given you is not a work around, but the official method to convert old textured brushes into assets for Blender 4.3. This method was officially recognized by the developers of blender in the following link.
https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.3/sculpt/#blender-43-sculpt-paint-texture
To keep things brief, I'll omit the asset library details. If you're having trouble adjusting to the asset library, then you can search this site (BSE) for questions relating to the asset-browser or any other asset related tag. Likewise, you can also check the Manual to learn how to use the asset library.
That being said, for my demonstration, I'll use Daniel's original file in Blender 4.3 instead appending the textured brushes from an old file. This is the link to Daniel's brush pack.
https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/5f235cc297f8815e74ffb90b
In the Outliner, change the Display Mode from View Layer to Blender File.

Find the brush(es) that you want to make into assets and right click to Mark as Asset.

For me, I organized the brush assets into a catalog which I made visible in the asset shelf as well. Now save the file in your asset library folder.

When you start any new project, the brushes should be available for use.

As a final note, I noticed that Daniel created this brush pack during Blender's 2.9 series. If I recall correctly, this was also during the time when Blender introduced a feature called vertex colors with color palettes which Daniel seemed to have incorporated into his textured brushes. So, switch from Material to Color Attribute to see if you can fully utilize Daniel's brushes.

